# How to clear all the routes to reduce the amount of memory?

Tags: flutter

Fot isnstance, in case someone don't care about closing routes, then how much spase can take navigation stack?

And is there a method or way to clean up all the navigation stack to clear some space?

For example if someone doing many pushes

```
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
Navigator.push...
...
// and at some point he would like to dismiss it all
[Navigator.cleanUp()] // for example
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to clear all the routes, and leave only the first you can use the `Navigator.popUntil` method. Like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route)=> route.isFirst);
// Pops routes until the current route's isFirst getter equals to true
// (until the current route is the first route
```

Comment: Does it work the way like, for instance the routes were:


`route0 > route1 > route2 > route3 > route2 > route3 > route4`
// and then
`Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route)=> route.isFirst);`


then the current route (and the only one) will be `route0` ?
right?